# Spacing Between Subplots in Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have subplots that come in pairs and then are stacked. I have them dynamically build based on how many runs I do (2 subplots side by side per run).

These subplots have titles on top (default position).

What I am running into is that the second pair's title, which resides under the first pair, is over lapping with the x-axis of the first pair.

I have tried tight_layout however it squished my graphs to the point of them being unusable.

I am looking for a way to stack pairs of subplots with enough room inbetween to have titles. Is there any way to add padding in between the stacked pairs. I also tried subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) but that didn't work either.

I figured this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Do the plots have the same xticks? You could use ax.set_xticklabels([]) to remove the numbers from only the top plots. That would stop the overlap with the title. Also if you post your code we can provide more help.

Comment: Try experimenting with the `hspace` argument of `subplots_adjust()`.  If you provide sample data it'll be easier to help with an exact solution.